# ReSetting the grid data on LoadComplete

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid and I want to reset the grid data when it is ready.I have a reason for doing this. My actual problem is complicated but here is a simple demo I created.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/313/) is a demo I created but the issue is that setting data on loadcomplete does not seem to show the data in the grid. The grid is just empty.

```
          var mydata = 
                [
                    {id:"1", DocGroupName: "x", DocList: "y", Mandatory: "z"}
                ];

                var mydata2 = [
                    {id:"2", DocGroupName: "yy", DocList: "rr", Mandatory: "gg"},
                     {id:"3", DocGroupName: "zz", DocList: "rr", Mandatory: "gg"}
                ];

            $("#list").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                height: "auto",
              colNames: ['id', 'Document Group Name','Document Name','No of Mandatory'],
                colModel :[
                    {name:'id', index:'id', width:55},
                    {name:'DocGroupName', index:'DocGroupName', width:90, editable: true},
                    {name:'DocList', index:'DocList', width:90, editable: true },
                    {name:'Mandatory', index:'Mandatory', width:90, editable: true}

                ],
                loadComplete: function(data)
                {

                  $('#list').jqGrid('clearGridData').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
                   data: mydata
                   }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1 }]);
                },
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                sortname: 'idcustomers',
                sortorder: 'asc',
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption: 'Customers',
                cellEdit: true,
                cellsubmit: 'clientArray'
            });
```

Comment: Which `datatype` have the grid which you use in your real application? Setting of data inside of `loadComplete` is not the best idea. There are many other callbacks. The usage of `.trigger('reloadGrid', ...)` inside of `loadComplete` is not good too. If you really need to do this then you should use `setTimeout` at least. It would be helpful if you describe the scenario, which you try to implement. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid? `mydata2` will be not used in your code and you set `data: mydata` twice.

Comment: Try to put your jqGrid parameters inside a function and when you want to change the data of your grid, do something like this:

$(grid_id).jqGrid('GridUnload');
grid_func(mydata);

https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/311/

Comment: @edibird88 Does this guarantee the grid is loaded?

Comment: @Oleg the version is 4.6.0 it is in the jsfiddle  I shared. The scenario is that I have multiple grids which are interrelated lets say grid2 depends on data loaded on grid1. So When grid1 is fully loaded and grid2 is fully loaded i reset the data of grid2 based on data on grid1.

Comment: @AmeteBlessed try it yourself. Just use GridUnload before the function call.

Comment: @AmeteBlessed: You demo has **only one grid**. I explained you in my first comment how you can fix the code  with minimal changes. The modified demo can look like https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/adgptkvj/315/. You can comment `data: mydata,` like and the code stay working. Thus I don't see much sense in your current construct if you have `datatype: "local"`. The callback `loadComplete` will be called **in many cases**. It's not the best choice in general. On sorting, paging and to on it will be called. Even if one calls `.trigger('reloadGrid',...)` then it will call `loadComplete` during reloading